# ApiController model binding properties not binding

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I'm currently trying out the new ApiController available with WebAPI - namely the POST method as I'm having no luck with binding the properties for the model.

This is my code for the ApiController:

```
public class GameController : ApiController
{
        public void Post([FromBody]GameVMTest gameVM)
        {
        }
}
```

In this example, I'm able to make a HTTP Post to this method. The GameVM property is initialised but none of the properties bind.

So I thought this might be caused by my method of HTTP Post and so I wrote another Post method but this time, using just a class that inherits a Controller class:

```
public class TestController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post(GameVMTest gameVM)
        {

        }
    }
```

I used the same HTTP Post to this TestController Post method and everything works just fine.

Any idea on why the property binding works for a class inheriting the Controller class but not the ApiController class?

Note: I have tried removing the [FromBody] attribute and this does nothing.
Note: GameVM property contains simple String & Int variables - nothing complex.

Thanks in advance.

Note:
The http post call is from an iOS app using Alamofire. 
Below is the JSON String passed to the two methods above:

"{\"isDirty\":1,\"courtName\":\"Court 1\",\"id\":11418,\"team1\":\"Kenja Hurricane\",\"team2\":\"Sons of Asia\",\"roundId\":528}"

Comment: What is the JS object that is being sent in the body of the post?

Comment: The few times this happened to me it was caused by some malformed json being send. For example using "left double quotation" marks instead of simple "double quotation" marks

Comment: Provide more info about how you are calling the WEB API method, that would be helpful in identifying the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this

https://lbadri.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/web-api-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc-6-asp-net-5/

Turns out the body of the request has to be very specific for WebAPI!!!